# Configure OpenLiberty server to use application's Logback configuration file

Tags: java, maven, open-liberty

I have a web application that uses `Open Liberty` for development — using the `Maven` plugin. Currently there is no custom/special configuration applied to the same, just the plugin in the `pom.xml` file for "development":

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.8</version>
</plugin>
```

The server configuration is quite simple as well (`../src/main/liberty/config/server.xml`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server description="app-name">
  <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />

  <!-- Server Configuration Feature Overview: https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/feature/ -->
  <featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-10.0</feature>
  </featureManager>

  <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="${default.http.port}" httpsPort="${default.https.port}" />

  <!-- ...already tried this, but I don't see anything different -->
  <!-- logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" / -->

  <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" trustDefaultCerts="true" />

  <webApplication id="app-name" contextRoot="/" location="${default.app.name}.war" />
</server>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to redirect all output logging from the `Open Liberty` server to use the main configuration file (from `Logback`) inside `../src/main/resources/logback.xml`.

Currently I don't have any special dependency to bridge anything to `Logback` — I just have `ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.4.5` with `runtime` scope, and `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.6` with `default` (or `compile`) scope.

Answer (score 0):

@x80486, Open Liberty's logging system does not have any integration with Logback or SLF4J, so I don't think you can do what you're asking.